# executing an oracle sql statement with a refcursor causes large execution time

Tags: oracle, odp.net-managed

I'm currently attempting to get a count of rows from a couple of tables. When I run it directly, it executes and returns in a couple of milliseconds. However, when I try to execute the same query with a refcursor return type, it is taking over a minute. I'm also running similar queries in other parts of the applications with this same format and they are executing fine.

Removing the inner join makes it run in a couple of milliseconds, but I need to keep the inner join to do some dynamic queries on the tables. It's also dependent on this specific where clause. Running where clauses on other columns does not cause this issue.

```sql
BEGIN OPEN:tableCount FOR SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2
ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
WHERE TABLEVALUE = 300;
END;
```

Not sure why wrapping a query with a refcursor with increase execution time by some much. Help on why this is occurring and how to resolve it would be great.

Comment: When you run it directly, is your IDE retrieving all the rows or only the top N rows?  Also, are the language settings the same between the two environments, and are there any implicit type conversions going on?  Finally, you might want to look for your query in `GV$SQL`, perhaps by filtering on the column `SQL_FULLTEXT`, to see exactly how Oracle is running the queries.  If there are two different `SQL_IDs`, find the execution plan for both: `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id => 'your ID'));`  (Performance tuning often requires a large amount of information.)

Comment: The performance issue is still occurring, even when I'm running this ref cursor on it's own. But in the typical running scenario, it will run with another ref cursor that will select the actual rows with top N rows. I'm running this query through odp.net core management access. I'm directly casting the count type as a nullable decimal on .NET's end. I tried looking through the sql table and the two variables that stood out was a high number of sorts (over 2k) and a high buffer_gets (around a million). I've also looked at the execution plan and it says 100% cpu time is in the SELECT.